# How to remove elements from array if part of the string matches, google-appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an array of data like this which is from two columns of my sheet

`[23849145412240785  ACTIVE, 23849143904010785  ACTIVE, 23849145429970785  ACTIVE, 23849145063370785  ACTIVE, 23849431077940785  PAUSED, 23849431077950785  ACTIVE, 23849431351900785  PAUSED, 23849433608970785  ACTIVE, 23849433622310785  ACTIVE, 23849433609000785  ACTIVE]`

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
let data = ss.getSheetByName('sheet1').getRange(2, 5, ss.getLastRow() - 1, 7).getValues();

function buildAlert(data) {
let   idStatus = data.map(function(column) {
   return column[0] +'  ' + column[5];
});
Logger.log(idStatus)


 let payload = {
   "blocks": [
     {
       "type": "section",
       "text": {
         "type": "mrkdwn",
         "text": ""
       }
     },
     {
       "type": "divider"
     },
     {
       "type": "section",
       "text": {
         "type": "mrkdwn",
         "text": idStatus
       }
     }
   ]
 };
 return payload;
}
```

And I am trying to remove all items from the array which contain PAUSED and add them to a new array. What is the best way to do this? thanks

Comment: So you want to remove every line of data where column 5 equals PAUSED  right ?

Comment: you could use `data.forEach` instead of `idStatus = data.map` and `push` to two different arrays - one for PAUSED and one for the rest

Comment: I'd just use a `filter(r => r[5] != "PAUSED")`

Comment: Did you try the suggested solution?

Comment: Vote to close since there is no any reaction from the asker. The question looks abandoned.